# How to show brand avatar in e. g. Gmail for non-Gmail e-mail addresses?

Tags: email, dns, header, gmail, avatar

Hej there,

I am currently try to find a solution for showing an avatar to the e-mails sent by own organization. Our e-mails are not bound to Google Workspace, because we don't want to pay for features that we're not using.

So far I added a BIMI DNS entry to our domain (currently without DKMI). I tried to figure out how other people / organizations solve the problem, but could find neither a BIMI TXT DNS entry on their domain nor an entry on Gravatar. Possibly they have an Google Workspace account, but maybe there is another solution I could not find yet.

Has anybody an idea how to get our avatar to e. g. Gmail e-mail boxes?

(Yes, I know about `X-Face` or `Face` header in e-mail, but I don't think that Gmail supports them – I also could not find them in any e-mail)

Answer (score 4):

The official solution is to reference a Verified Mark Certificate (VMC) in your BIMI record. This handles all of your email addresses at once. Your logo needs to be registered as a trademark, and you will need to purchase a VMC from DigiCert or Entrust. The cost to register a trademark is roughly $660, plus attorney fees, and the cost to purchase a VMC is $1,499 per year.

The solution provided by @HTeaMeuLeu is a free alternative for anyone who can't afford a VMC.

1. Create a [Google account](https://accounts.google.com/signup) with your company's email address.
2. Change the profile picture to your company's logo.
3. Wait up to 48 hours for the logo to become visible in the inbox.

Do not create the Google account using the "To manage my business" option. This account type isn't able to change its profile picture, and the account type can't be changed after its created.

**For everyone else:** 
First, you will need complete the BIMI specification. Then, you will need to complete any additional requirements that each email service provider may have to display the logo in their inbox. This [tutorial](https://medium.com/p/77d713cb9e45) walks you through the process and explains everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a detailed article on how to do this for a newsletter: [Logos in the Inbox: Gmail](https://blog.peakinbox.com/2020/08/24/logos-in-gmail/).

You basically need to create a Google account *without* Gmail (at https://accounts.google.com/SignUpWithoutGmail) and setup your image there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem with this is, that it requires me to add all e-mail addresses we are using – and that is a lot! Therefore some kind of catch-all e-mail addresses would be fine, but those are only available if you use Google Workspace. Do you have any other solutions for this?

Comment: Yeh with a certificate and a copyrighted logo, but thats all super expensive.