# how to make my website logo show in email?

Tags: php, email, outlook, gmail, swiftmailer

i developed a web application with personalized email through my cpanel (admin@tailorsmind.com), connected it with my application through php (swiftmailer) in the source code, emails are going through for registration, login and forgot password but the problem I am simply having is my website logo won't simply just show up in each email that is sent.
I logged in the email in outlook, tried checking for image settings but couldn't get one.
also created a gmail account with the email and uploaded a logo but still not getting the result i am looking for . Please help !!!
[image: website email logo not showing]

it just keeps showing that question mark you see there and i don't want that.

Comment: Here’s a previous similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70364333/how-to-show-brand-avatar-in-e-g-gmail-for-non-gmail-e-mail-addresses/70365004#70365004 Make sure the image you uploaded is in a supported format (JPG or PNG should be fine).

Comment: i already did that about two days ago but still showing the question mark